# Servlet html not printing form

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

similar problem to one i had before however th previous work around does not work this time . The code concerned with the  is throwing the errors shown below[image]

if the image wont load here's the code

```
    LongLivedCookie c =
    new LongLivedCookie("accessCount",
                      String.valueOf(count+1));
    response.addCookie(c);
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String title = "Access Count Servlet";
    String docType =
      "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 " +
      "Transitional//EN\">\n";
     out.println(docType +
            "<HTML>\n" +
            "<HEAD><TITLE>" + title + "</TITLE></HEAD>\n" +
            "<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FDF5E6\">\n" +
            "<CENTER>\n" +
            "<H1>" + title + "</H1>\n" +
            "<H2>This is visit number " +
            count + " by this browser.</H2>\n" +
            "<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action='Question_3.jsp'           

            padding="10" >" +
             "<button type="submit">Submit</button> " +
            "</CENTER></BODY></HTML>");
      }
     }
```

Comment: I am not able to see anything in the picture... :)

Comment: sorry , i've added in the code now

Comment: HTML does not belong in servlets. Learn how to use JSP for HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 0):

Java strings start and end with quotes , If you want to use quotes within a string as in your case then you should escape them with \ , like " id=\"xyz\""

Comment: using the escape I have he line as this "<form "id=\"form\" "name=\"form\" method=\"post\" action='Question_3.jsp' "padding=\"10\" >" + but it still throwing errors

Answer (score 0):

The code should escape the double quotes within the String literals.

```
 out.println(docType +
            "<HTML>\n" +
            "<HEAD><TITLE>" + title + "</TITLE></HEAD>\n" +
            "<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FDF5E6\">\n" +
            "<CENTER>\n" +
            "<H1>" + title + "</H1>\n" +
            "<H2>This is visit number " +
            count + " by this browser.</H2>\n" +
            "<form id=\"form\" name=\"form\" method=\"post\" action='Question_3.jsp'           
            padding=\"10\" >" +
             "<button type=\"submit\">Submit</button> " +
            "</CENTER></BODY></HTML>");
      }
```